# Searching in Active Directory with Java using ID from another trusted Domain

Tags: java, active-directory

I am trying to search for the members of an Active Directory group in one Domain (A.domain.com) in Java using An ID that is trusted and in another Domain (B.lmig.com). I know that the trust is configured correctly as I can connect with the id and perform the search via ldp and ADUC successfully. However using the following code:

```
Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://A.domain.com:389/");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");

env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "id@B.domain.com");
env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "*******");

env.put(Context.REFERRAL, "follow");
InitialLdapContext ctx = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);

String base = "DC=A,DC=domain,DC=com";

String filter = "(memberof=CN=grouptest,OU=someplace,OU=somewhere,OU=thegroups,DC=A,DC=domain,DC=com)";

SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);

NamingEnumeration<SearchResult> answer = ctx.search(base, filter, controls);
```

Results in the following exception, which seems to indicate the user id does not exists.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C090334, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 525, vece
```

My question is if there is a certain setting or something I am missing that will tell Java that the ID is located in the "B.domain.com" domain and should authenticate throught that domain, while performing the actual search on the "A.domain.com" domain? Since I can perfrom the search via LDP and ADUC fine I must be missing a config or referencing the domains wrong or something.

Answer (score 0):

LDAP error code 49 is invalid credentials. The data 525 indicates no such user.

In my experience, the `security_principal` is generally a distinguished name (DN), not an email address.

In our system we search AD for the email with `(sAMAccountName=id@b.domain.com)` to obtain a `DN`. Then the `DN` is used for the `security_principal`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I looked up the DN and attempted to use that for the connection (CN=id,OU=App Service Accounts,dc=B,dc=domain,dc=com). However this resulted in the same error message being thrown.